# SSH E-mail login alert if SSH port is as NAT

Tags: debian, ssh, iptables, nat

Can you help me with this problem please?
How can I set e-mail alerting after SSH login when port 22 is NATed? I use Linux Debian 7.
I have used these iptables rules:

```
eth0 - external network, eth1 - internal network    
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: still not clear what the question is, when you looking for an email altert after login: http://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful

Comment: @bersch, Thanks I tried it. But it does not work. I need alert after open SSH session, but SSH server runs on next system, behind NAT. This alert have to generate on this system which works as NAT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to generate email alerts when this host NATs ssh to another server, then log the connections and use a log monitoring tool to send the notification.  A tool like `logcheck` will send notifications hourly.  Others can be configured to send notifications as events appear in the log.

If you want to generate the message on the target server try using `/etc/host.allow` rules.  The first rule should accept local (not-NATed) connections.   The second should accept connections (NATed) and send an email. Here is an example: (change you@example.com to your email address).

```
sshd:   192.168.0.0/16 127.0.0.1 [::1] [fe::/8]

sshd:   ALL : \
        spawn (/bin/echo "SSH connection to %N from %n[%a] allowed" | \
        /usr/bin/mailx -s "SSH Allowed" you@example.com)
```

Comment: thanks. Paragraph 1 is my case. When you see to my iptables rules in first post, how can effectively log activity with iptables please? On my machine that works as NAT runs special tool on port 22 that forwards network traffic after analysis (SSH session and comands are recorded).

Comment: @Mato If you are running a tool to snoop the SSH session just have it email on connection, or wrap it and log as in the second case.

Comment: Thanks. So I have made file /etc/host.allow and I put this: (I have used sendemail): 
sshd:   ALL : \
        spawn (/bin/echo "SSH connection to %N from %n[%a] allowed" | \
        sendEmail -o tls=no -f my@mail.tld -t to@mail.tld -u "SSH LOGIN" -m "message" -s smtp_parameters -xu login -xp password) but it does not work... Any idea please?